# Why can't read fill variables when used at the end of a pipe?

Tags: linux, bash

Why is the output empty?

```
echo "a b c d" | read X Y Z V
echo $X
```

I thought it would be `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that, in order to run the `read` command with its input redirected from the `echo`, a new subshell process is spawned. This process reads the values, assigns them to the variables - and then exits; then the second `echo` command is run. To demonstrate this you can do the second `echo` and the `read` both from a subshell:

```
$ echo "a b c d" | ( read X Y Z V; echo $X )
a
```

Answer (score 6):

In Bash, you can do a couple of different things to accomplish that:

A here string:

```
read X Y Z V <<< $(echo "a b c d"); echo $X
```

Process substitution:

```
read X Y Z V < <(echo "a b c d"); echo $X
```

A here document with command substitution:

```
read X Y Z V <<EOF
$(echo "a b c d")
EOF
echo $X
```

The here document method will also work with POSIX shells in addition to Bash.

If you're reading from a file instead of from the output of another command, it's a little simpler.

Comment: Another one you should add: echo a b c d | while read X Y Z V; do echo $X; done

Comment: @Zan: the problem with that is the same as in the question. After the `while` loop, the values are gone since the while loop creates a subshell.

Comment: Yes, but in most cases you only need those variables inside the loop.

Comment: @Zan: I've written many such `while` loops where I needed the values afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is because `echo "a b c d" | read X Y Z V` and `echo $X` are separate statements (I'm not sure of the exact term)? So one doesn't know about the other.

EDIT: Give `echo "a b c d" | ( read X Y Z V; echo $X )` a try...